# How to display the tabs "All Updates" "Call logs", ... on the case Chatter component on Case

Tags: page-layout, sales-cloud, casefeed

I cannot manage to make the tabs "All Updates", "Call logs",... appear on the chatter component on the case page layout. How it looks on my org on Salescloud(sandbox):
[image: my sandbox feed]

On a playground:
[image: playground feed]

It created an *Feed-Based Layout* and checked the *Feed Filter Options* but it does not help...
[image: filter options]

How can I do ?

Comment: What object are you doing this on?  I ask because some standard objects like `Case` have a different way to configure Chatter/Feeds vs Custom Objects.

Comment: @ScottPelak It's on the Case object

Comment: The `Chatter` component seems to be composed of the `Chatter Publisher` component on top of the `Chatter Feed` component.    Maybe try using `Chatter Publisher` + `Chatter Feed` instead of just `Chatter`.

Comment: @ScottPelak thanks for the idea, but it looks exactly the same on the Chatter feed than on Chatter component.

Comment: @Musisold - where you able to solve this?